# How to install a PowerShell module on multiple machines via PowerShell script itself

Tags: powershell, automation, powershell-module

I need to install Bitlocker related module on various machines in my environment. I can't install it one by one manually. I need to automate the installation. Can someone point me in the right direction and provide me pointers.

I can't find any previous questions on this. I saw below question but we don't have NuGet on all the machines. 
[Use nuget to install PowerShell modules at user machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14997134/use-nuget-to-install-powershell-modules-at-user-machine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage **PowerShell Gallery** features for this.

**Pre-Requisite:** Ensure that you have the PowerShellGet module. This module comes witht he Windows Management Framework (WMF) 5.0 or you can use an MSI based installer and include this in PowerShell 3 and 4. You can push this via SCCM if it is not there already.

**Required Cmdlets:** Use below cmdlet to perform required operations. You can use these cmdlets in a script and run that against multiple computers in your environment.

```
#Check if module exists using Find-Module cmdlet
Find-Module xBitlocker

#Install the module using the Install-Module cmdlet
Install-Module -Name xBitlocker -Force

#Check module is on current machine already using below cmdlet
Get-Module -Name xBitlocker

#Save the module on local machine without installing
Save-Module -Name xBitlocker -Path <path here>

#Install the module using the below cmdlet
Uninstall-Module -Name xBitlocker -Force
```

You can use these cmdlets and create script to run against multiple machines.
You can change `xBitlocker` with another module name as well.

**Reference:** [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/)

Comment: Wow, that was fast. I will try it out. Thanks.